# Free product of infinite many groups is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

Let $\{G_i\mid i\in I\}$ an infinite family of (not trivial) groups. Is it true that the [free product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) $\ast_{i\in I} G_i$ is not finitely generated?

I think it's true, I just need confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

$$\;^*_{i\in I} G_i=\langle\;a_1,\ldots,a_n\;\rangle\;$$

But in each $\;a_i\;$ appears **only a finite number** of elements from a finite number of groups $\;G_i\;$  and thus the same is true for the whole set $\{a_1,...,a_n\}\;$